# Importing Custom Class .h file into AppDelegate.h with relative route doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4, compiler-errors, include-path

In my Cocoa Application I have created a Custom View Class (subclass of NSView), named "DragAndDropView". Its .h and .m files are placed in the same folder than the AppDelegate.h.

Into the AppDelegate.h, I need to declare an outlet of my DragAndDropView. It looks like this:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <DragAndDropView.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
@private
    NSWindow        *window;

    DragAndDropView *dragAndDropView;

    // Files
    NSFileManager   *fileMgr;
}

// Outlets
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet DragAndDropView *dragAndDropView;

@end
```

With the import of my class (#import ), I become the following error:

```
'DragAndDropView.h' file not found
```

Anyone knows how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use quotes instead of angled brackets in your import line. i.e. this:

```
#import "DragAndDropView.h"
```

instead of this:

```
#import <DragAndDropView.h>
```

In essence, the former is for importing headers from your project, the latter is for importing headers from system libraries.